# Can't I answer my question, which is marked as duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I've posted this question:

[How to set Button inner properties in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51321243/how-to-set-button-inner-properties-in-code-behind)

It was marked as a duplicate, but the answer in the so-called original question:

[Set a property of a nested element in an WPF style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40657840/set-a-property-of-a-nested-element-in-an-wpf-style)

Is not helpful to me, that question has only one answer that is already marked "Correct".

I've subsequently found / made a solution to my problem and I want to post it as an answer to my own question, but I can't. It also would not make sense to post my answer in the other "Original" question, since it already has one "Correct" marked answer and my answer really would not be helpful in the context of that question.

Is there any way I can post my answer so it can be helpful to others perhaps?

Comment: Duplicate questions cannot be answered without first getting them reopened

Comment: And your answer doesn't fit on the duplicate, right?

Comment: @rene Yes my answer is specific to my question. It won't make sense to post on the other question.

Comment: @Shiasu-sama Okay, it is open now, you can post your answer

Comment: No question can have more than one 'correct' (marked as the answer with a check) response. The validity of the other responses is gauged by the upvote/downvote tally for each response.

Comment: Please make sure your answer is something from which people may learn something, not a wall of code.

Comment: I'm finding that the duplicate tag is the "easy" button for those with the power. At least it seems that way. If a question is anywhere in the ball park of a previous question... Duplicate. Nevermind that the person is attempting to clarify a different but similar question.

Comment: @D-Klotz It's up to you to explain _why_ your question is different from the similar one—and why the answers to that other one don't answer your question (which they often do even if the question isn't identical). Also, it's hardly easy to search for dups on Stack Overflow. Most askers aren't lazy or stupid; they fail to find the dup because Stack Overflow's defective search makes it hard for experienced users to find dups and damn near impossible for newcomers—that's why we have so many duplicate questions in the first place.

Comment: Personally don't see how your answer is different *(except for your own specific styling code)* to the duplicate questions answer, should be marked as a duplicate and shouldn't be reopened.

Comment: @Lankymart looks to me like the question isn't an obvious duplicate as OP states he doesn't want to use XAML whereas the dupe does, but the answer OP has provided does in fact answer the duplicate question and not his own

Comment: @WhatsThePoint they use XAML regardless, it's just programmatically set.

Comment: @D-Klotz I'm finding it frustrating that you have over 700 rep but don't understand the fundamental purpose of [so] *(hint: it's not to answer the same questions in slightly different guises over and over)*.

Comment: Note that you can self-answer before you actually post a question (check the "Answer your own question" box below the "Post Your Question" button).

Comment: @chepner I did not have the answer when I posted the question. Only after two days; I figured out a solution to my problem.

Comment: @abarnert In principal I agree except that in some cases people don't believe they have a duplicate to begin with. By the time it is marked duplicate it is usually to late. Sure you can petition but honestly, should it take a meta post to make it really change for your post?

Comment: @Lankymart really? Yes I understand, but in reality imho there is something there that needs addressing. How much work does the duplicate system introduce for the people working it? What does it REALLY solve? You still have duplicates. Does someone come along and delete the duplicates? I am starting to believe that the dups should simply be left alone to evolve or die on the vine. Why introduce the extra overhead and frustrations.

Comment: If YOU think it is a duplicate, fine. But imho actually marking it shouldn't stop the editing and evolution of the post. Marking it as a duplicate should simply be a tag that someone can notice with links.

Comment: @D-Klotz What it solves: There’s one place where all of the good answers to a question appear, which can be indexed by Google, linked from lists of “canon dups” for the regulars to find more easily, etc. The answers are more likely to be updated over time when they aren’t duplicated across 100 questions. The voting is going to be more accurate when it’s concentrated on one 4-year-old question than 100 fly-by-night dups. And so on.

Comment: @D-Klotz But, at any rate, if you want to completely change the system, you should write a proposal, post it, and defend it, not just use it as an argument for why people shouldn’t follow the existing rules and use the existing system in the middle of a comment thread.

Comment: Simple: Edit your question to include your answer!

Comment: @taw :| is this a joke?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want someone to trust the answer on the duplicate is not answering your question, you'll have to explain why by editing your question.

This will bump your question on the page and with a little chance gather 5 reopen votes (or 1 gold badge owner in one of the question tag). If a gold badge owner has voted to close your question you can try to ping (comment with @name) them if after some time your question didn't gather enough votes for reopening. But **pay attention** to be **very clear** in the comment on **why** you're asking for reopen.

Once the question is reopened you may answer yourself.

That said, be prepared people may not agree with you and your question may stay closed.

Comment: How does a normal user know about the 5 person rule? I see this "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.".  This part of it seems cumbersome. Edit the post, maybe it will be opened.

Comment: @D-Klotz that should be a different question. If it's a good formulated feature-request, i think it will be positive received.

Answer (score 1):

There are often several interpretations of what a question is really asking. There are often several ways to answer a question. Having an answer marked as "accepted" merely means that it solved the problem for the original asker.

If you agree that your question is similar to the duplicate then you could write another answer on that duplicate. This is good for the site because the duplicate then has another way of solving that sort of problem. Your question remains there pointing at the duplicate which now has both answers. This gives people searching a bigger chance of finding either your question or the duplicate and from them both answers.

Comment: They already stated that they feel the answer to their question would not make sense as an answer to the duplicate target.

Comment: @TinyGiant in their opinion but I would beg to differ as it's just a variation of Point 2. in the existing answer on the duplicate.

Comment: @Lankymart that has no bearing on whether the OP _feels_ that their answer would or would not make sense as an answer to the duplicate target. The advice given in this answer says that _"If you agree that your question is similar to the duplicate"_, while it is stated in the OP that they do not agree with that, which was the point of my comment. This is the equivalent of someone asking a programming question such as "How do I do X without doing Y?" and someone answering "You could do Y".

Comment: @TinyGiant Point taken.

Comment: If an answer (which is becoming the focus of many duplicates) has an answer added that greatly improves upon the original answer - I agree. What I don't find useful is when I look inside and see answers that solve the same problem in a slightly different way. It could be style, it could be because the OP of a dup wanted to make sure his or her answer was really answered. To me this adds to the confusion unless you are already and expert in the field. If that is the audience we only wish to cater to... then fine.

Answer (score -8):

In my experience, having a question marked as possible duplicate is extremely annoying. Who gives a monkey's whether it is a duplicate?
In 99% of the cases where my questions have been marked as a duplicate, they were not duplicates, the moderator concerned obviously did not read the question properly, or the solution given was irrelevant.

Comment: You only have 5 questions closed as a duplicate and none of those seem incorrect. Also note that most often not *moderators* but users with either a gold tag badge or 5 users with close vote privileges mark questions as duplicate. They can't all be bad at reading ...

Comment: @rene I think in each case, the OP is the ONLY person who can tell definitively whether a proposed solution to their problem actually works.

Comment: true that, doesn't mean others can offer the duplicate as answer.

Comment: I give a monkey's about duplicates.  When you have too many questions (asking the same thing) and their answers, you create a pile of 'same' - this makes it harder to find stuff as the noise ratio is greater.  Having fewer questions (and most different from each other, gives me a chance to find my answer faster) - I prefer quality over quantity..

Comment: Again, [so] is unwelcoming apparently...but *"who gives a monkey's"*?? - \**holds head in hands\**

Comment: @SteveStaple yes, nothing stopping them checking the solutions on the duplicate question(s).